# How to find the count of numbers which are divisible by 7?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an integer `N`, how to efficiently find the count of numbers which are divisible by 7 (their reverse should also be divisible by 7) in the range:

- `[0, 10^N - 1]`

Example:

For `N=2`, answer:

- `4 {0, 7, 70, 77}`

[All numbers from 0 to 99 which are divisible by 7 (also their reverse is divisible)]

My approach, simple brute-force:

- initialize count to zero
- run a loop from `i=0` till end
- if `a(i) % 7 == 0 && reverse(a(i)) % 7 == 0`, then we increase the count

Note:

- `reverse(123) = 321`, `reverse(1200) = 21`, for example!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: when is something divisable by `7`?

Comment: When x%7=0, but it won't be efficient to check for each number !!

Comment: @ShalilniTomar: no but there are "tricks" to know efficiently if something is dividable by seven. and you can use that to calculate the number of items.

Comment: It can be done by digit-dp(dynamic-programming)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't see how divisibility rules (other than modulus and digit dynamic-programming) would help in the case of arbitrary N. Could you please give some indication?

Comment: You can use sign of divisibility by 7, https://blog.rinatussenov.com/useful-math-divisibility-signs-fbc08baf20c6

Comment: What do you define as the *reverse* of a number? The number that arises from reversing the decimal representation of it?

Comment: what are the bounds on N? cc @ShaliniTomar

Comment: @v78 what difference would the bounds on N make the answer you would offer? (Assuming it's too big for brute force.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן, I want to know if it is 1000 or 10^6 or 10^18 or any arbitrary integer(which makes computing answer almost impossible) to help me think of the algorithm.

Comment: Assume N<=10000 and I feel one line formula can solve this problem as well...

Comment: @v78 N is the exponent in this case. I'm not sure what you mean by 10^6 or 10^18. Did you mean N=6 and N=18? Even in that small case, how would your answer be different for N = 18 or higher (assuming brute force is not an option)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recursive solution using digit dp technique for any digits.

```
long long call(int pos , int Mod ,int revMod){
    if(pos == len ){
        if(!Mod && !revMod)return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    if(dp[pos][Mod][revMod] != -1 )return dp[pos][Mod][revMod] ;

    long long res =0;
    for(int i= 0; i<= 9; i++ ){
        int revValue =(base[pos]*i + revMod)%7;
        int curValue = (Mod*10 + i)%7;
        res += call(pos+1, curValue,revValue) ;
    }

    return dp[pos][Mod][revMod] = res ;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do it for large 'n' using matrix-exponentiation ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what happens mod 7 when we add a digit, `d`, to a prefix, `abc`.

```
10 * abc + d =>
  (10 mod 7 * abc mod 7) mod 7 + d mod 7

reversed number:

abc + d * 10^(length(prefix) =>
  abc mod 7 + (d mod 7 * 10^3 mod 7) mod 7
```

Note is that we only need the count of prefixes of `abc mod 7` for each such remainder, not the actual prefixes.

Comment: Can you explain it with the help of small cases like N=4 or N=5, some psuedocode will surely help. Thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: For the reversed number you need REVERSE(abc) + d*10^prefix_len  = REVERSE(abc) mod 7 +...    For each prefix length you need counts for all 49 combinations of (x%7, REVERSE(x)%7)

Comment: @MattTimmermans Can you please write a detailed answer or explanation , it will be really helpful :-)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to calculate answer with your method as we have to reverse(abc), and we don't have its count, cuz we haven't stored exact prefixes, we have only stored abc%7 for each number {0,6}

Comment: @ShaliniTomar yes, my answer seems to be only part of the solution. We need to associate counts with one state for both prefix mod 7 and reverse_prefix mod 7.

Comment: @MattTimmersman Will just calculating g=(a)^n be enough or do I have to do something more, multiply something else to it as well ?

Answer (score 3):

Let **COUNTS(n,f,r)** be the number of n-digit numbers such that **n%7 = f** and **REVERSE(n)%7** = r

The counts are easy to calculate for **n=1**:

**COUNTS(1,f,r) = 0** when **f!=r**, since a 1-digit number is the same as its reverse.

**COUNTS(1,x,x) = 1** when **x >= 3**, and

**COUNTS(1,x,x) = 2** when **x < 3**, since 7%3=0, 8%3=1, and 9%3=2

The counts for other lengths can be figured out by calculating what happens when you add each digit from 0 to 9 to the numbers characterized by the previous counts.

At the end, **COUNTS(N,0,0)** is the answer you are looking for.

In python, for example, it looks like this:

```
def getModCounts(len):
    counts=[[0]*7 for i in range(0,7)]
    if len<1:
        return counts
    if len<2:
        counts[0][0] = counts[1][1] = counts[2][2] = 2
        counts[3][3] = counts[4][4] = counts[5][5] = counts[6][6] = 1
        return counts
    prevCounts = getModCounts(len-1)
    for f in range(0,7):
        for r in range(0,7):
            c = prevCounts[f][r]
            rplace=(10**(len-1))%7
            for newdigit in range(0,10):
                newf=(f*10 + newdigit)%7
                newr=(r + newdigit*rplace)%7
                counts[newf][newr]+=c
    return counts

def numFwdAndRevDivisible(len):
    return getModCounts(len)[0][0]

#TEST
for i in range(0,20):
    print("{0} -> {1}".format(i, numFwdAndRevDivisible(i)))
```

See if it gives the answers you're expecting.  If not, maybe there's a bug I need to fix:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 22
4 -> 206
5 -> 2113
6 -> 20728
7 -> 205438
8 -> 2043640
9 -> 20411101
10 -> 204084732
11 -> 2040990205
12 -> 20408959192
13 -> 204085028987
14 -> 2040823461232
15 -> 20408170697950
16 -> 204081640379568
17 -> 2040816769367351
18 -> 20408165293673530
19 -> 204081641308734748
```

This is a pretty good answer when counting up to N is reasonable -- *way* better than brute force, which counts up to 10^N.

For very long lengths like N=10^18 (you would probably be asked for a the count mod 1000000007 or something), there is a next-level answer.

Note that there is a linear relationship between the counts for length *n* and the counts for length **n+1**, and that this relationship can be represented by a 49x49 matrix.  You can exponentiate this matrix to the **N**th power using exponentiation by squaring in O(log N) matrix multiplications, and then just multiply by the single digit counts to get the length N counts.

Comment: Yes, it is giving perfect answer, all you need to do , is modulo the final number by e, example, for n=5, answer will be 206%e, where 'e' is a prime number of nine digits. We do this so the final answers is always of 9 digits or less :-)

Comment: My 2nd question : - How can we calculate this for large 'n', say n<=1000000000; can we derive a general formula for any 'N' ? Thankyou so much :-)

Comment: For such large 'n' , can we do matrix exponentiation or a general formula can be arrived?

Comment: Can you explain the matrix-exponentiation part a bit? Say the initial 7X7 matrix is a. So for any given n, we have to do g= (a)^n, final answer is:- g(0)(0) , right ?

Comment: In the 49cross49 matrix, what will be the meaning of a(i)(j), does it mean prefixes with modulo=i and reverse modulo=j ?

Comment: I don't know of a closed-form formula for the count.  In the 49x49 matrix, A[c*7+d][a*7+b] is the multiple of COUNTS(n,a,b) that goes into COUNTS(n+1,c,d)

Comment: You said, after the matrix exponentiation, multiply it by single digit counts to get the final answer. What does that mean ?

Comment: What will be the values in the initial large matrix, will it be the counts of prefix-length-'0' that go into prefix-length-'1' or counts of prefix-lengths-'1' that go into prefix-length-'2'

Comment: I don't see a proper recurrence relation between matrix forms, like f(1)= [matirx]*f(2), but I am not sure that multiplying that matrix again and again can give values of f(3),f(4),..etc.

Comment: Let me explain in detail : - - > the cells from prefix length-'1' which contribute to cell(0,0) of prefix-length-'2' are:- [0 0 ,
0 0 ,
1 2 ,
2 4 ,
2 4 ,
3 6 ,
4 1 ,
4 1 ,
5 3 ,
6 5  ]  And the cells which (of prefix-length-'2') which contribute to (0,0) cell of prefix-length-'3' are:- [0 0, 
0 0 ,
1 6 ,
2 5 ,
2 5 ,
3 4 ,
4 3 ,
4 3 ,
5 2 ,
6 1  ]  As we can see both of the cell groups have not exact similarity, so same matrix can't be used and multiplied again and again :(